# Date picker to get only date month shows 00

Tags: vb.net

I need only date from a date picker but it gives date and time. I searched for the solutions and find. But when I use month shows 00. For today's date it will be like 00/27/2017. I am using vb.net 2012

```
rdate = dtrdate.Value.Date.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
rdate = dtrdate.Value.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Lower case m gives you the minutes, so for instance, if you also wanted to include time then it would be

```
rdate = dtrdate.Value.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: If I answered your question, then please mark it as so. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers